# SAS: adding a column with if

Tags: sas

how to create a column with if construction? for example create JOB column with values from column NAME with job names
if name="actor" then job = 1 , elseif name="analyst" then job = 2 ...etc

Comment: Google is your friend. Please see SAS training videos here http://support.sas.com/training/tutorial/ Specifically Conditional Logic video. If you prefer text read the doc here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/68381/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n10h0x7gl1xj7in1ad8shhkcging.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you almost have it.  It's really simple:

```
data new;
set old;
if name = 'actor' then job=1;
else if name = 'analysts' then job = 2;
run;
```

Seems like you could of figured this out by yourself

Comment: Always so close.... :) thanks for the answer. And can I use elseif many times ? By adding elseif name = babysitter then job = 3?